# Which Xml class to use for an array of XmlNode[]

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I've generated some classes from an XSD which has worked fine, and I'm building up the the data and serializing it to XML, everything is working fine.

Except I have one property which is an array of `XmlNode`, and I can't for my life figure out what class to use. Not an XML expert.

The property in the class that was generated is as follows.

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
public string type
{
    get
    {
        return this.typeField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.typeField = value;
    }
}
```

And I've built up everything around it to this point:

```
timeInterval.AdditionalData = new[]
{
    new AdditionalDataType()
    {
        type = "DOECode",
        Any = new XmlNode[] { ... }
    }
 };
```

The expected Xml after serializing should be like:

```
<AdditionalData type="DOECode">11</AdditionalData>
```

What class can i put into the 'Any' to populate with a inner-text value, without changing the generated class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have solved the problem.

Solution was to create an XmlDocument, and create a node from the the document.

```
var node = (new XmlDocument()).CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Text, string.Empty, string.Empty);
```

Then assign the InnerText value:

```
node.InnerText = reason.ExportCode;
```

It generated the following.

```
<AdditionalData type="DOECode">TEST CODE</AdditionalData>
```